# Google API Explorer doesn't create Compute Engine VM instance

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-apis-explorer

as in title, I am trying to use Google API Explorer to run vm instance. I am using [instances.insert](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert) for this, but I can't get it to work. After successfuly executing the call I can not see any newly creted vm instance in https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances

The request I am trying to execute is copied from `Equivalent REST request` in Google Cloud Console `Create an instance` web page :

```
{
  "name": "some-name",
  "machineType": "projects/my-project-id/zones/europe-west3-c/machineTypes/f1-micro",
  "displayDevice": {
    "enableDisplay": false
  },
  "metadata": {
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "startup-script",
        "value": "#! /bin/bash\necho hello\nEOF"
      }
    ]
  },
  "tags": {
    "items": []
  },
  "disks": [
    {
      "type": "PERSISTENT",
      "boot": true,
      "mode": "READ_WRITE",
      "autoDelete": true,
      "deviceName": "some-name",
      "initializeParams": {
        "sourceImage": "projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-10-buster-v20200910",
        "diskType": "projects/my-project-id/zones/europe-west3-c/diskTypes/pd-standard",
        "diskSizeGb": "10",
        "labels": {}
      },
      "diskEncryptionKey": {}
    }
  ],
  "canIpForward": false,
  "networkInterfaces": [
    {
      "subnetwork": "projects/my-project-id/regions/europe-west3/subnetworks/default",
      "accessConfigs": [
        {
          "name": "External NAT",
          "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT",
          "networkTier": "PREMIUM"
        }
      ],
      "aliasIpRanges": []
    }
  ],
  "description": "",
  "labels": {},
  "scheduling": {
    "preemptible": false,
    "onHostMaintenance": "MIGRATE",
    "automaticRestart": true,
    "nodeAffinities": []
  },
  "deletionProtection": false,
  "reservationAffinity": {
    "consumeReservationType": "ANY_RESERVATION"
  },
  "serviceAccounts": [
    {
      "email": "some-number-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
      "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "shieldedInstanceConfig": {
    "enableSecureBoot": false,
    "enableVtpm": true,
    "enableIntegrityMonitoring": true
  },
  "confidentialInstanceConfig": {
    "enableConfidentialCompute": false
  }
}
```

Here is the response with status `200`

```
{
  "id": "2981010757915612255",
  "name": "operation-1602235056020-5b1396b5c5cee-e0e30499-4d06ce75",
  "zone": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/zones/europe-west3-c",
  "operationType": "insert",
  "targetLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/zones/europe-west3-c/instances/ams2-linux-race-1",
  "targetId": "1541614827291382879",
  "status": "RUNNING",
  "user": "email@gmail.com",
  "progress": 0,
  "insertTime": "2020-10-09T02:17:36.818-07:00",
  "startTime": "2020-10-09T02:17:36.821-07:00",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/zones/europe-west3-c/operations/operation-1602235056020-5b1396b5c5cee-e0e30499-4d06ce75",
  "kind": "compute#operation"
}
```

I have the same issue with C# code example from https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert#examples

I can execute the same request without errors and in response I am getting this

```
{
   "clientOperationId":null,
   "creationTimestamp":null,
   "description":null,
   "endTime":null,
   "error":null,
   "httpErrorMessage":null,
   "httpErrorStatusCode":null,
   "id":3283200477858999168,
   "insertTime":"2020-10-09T00:46:55.187-07:00",
   "kind":"compute#operation",
   "name":"operation-1602229614262-5b1382701b989-381126a6-cc145485",
   "operationType":"insert",
   "progress":0,
   "region":null,
   "selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/zones/europe-west3-c/operations/operation-1602229614262-5b1382701b989-381126a6-cc145485",
   "startTime":"2020-10-09T00:46:55.189-07:00",
   "status":"RUNNING",
   "statusMessage":null,
   "targetId":2365846324436118401,
   "targetLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/zones/europe-west3-c/instances/some-name",
   "user":"email@gmail.com",
   "warnings":null,
   "zone":"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/zones/europe-west3-c",
   "ETag":null
}
```

but I can't see any new instance beeing created...

Does any one know what is the issue here?
The Compute Engine API is enabled. Result of `gcloud services list`:

```
NAME                              TITLE
...
compute.googleapis.com            Compute Engine API
...
```

Comment: Are you sure to be in the correct project?

Comment: Ok, I was able to get help on serverfault.com - https://serverfault.com/questions/1037166/google-api-explorer-doesnt-create-compute-engine-vm-instance

Answer (score 0):

Can you please double check if Compute Engine Api is enabled and post the result in your question.

```
gcloud services list
```

I believe your Compute Engine Api is not enabled.

Comment: `compute.googleapis.com            Compute Engine API` is listed